# How to redirect url from Zend Rest Application?

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework, redirect

I have an application where I receive a url & use Zend rest client to post the url to another url. The other url is received by a Codeigniter application. I want to do a redirect in that codeigniter application. The redirect produces correct response but the url does not change.

How can I redirect correctly in my application?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to run the CodeIgniter redirect method

```
$this->load->helper("url");

redirect($url);
```

or you could use PHP's built in header redirect

```
header("Location: {$url}");
```

Both of these example require the `$url` to be set before they are called...

Good luck

Comment: I know about this but the thing is my codeigniter app is running under Zend application. The response is first captured by Zend application & then using Zend Rest Client, I make an internal request to my codeigniter application. I need to redirect from that codeigniter app. The redirect works but the browser url does not change.

Comment: If you are making an HTTP call to your CodeIgniter app from your Zend app, it will never be able to redirect the users browser directly. What you will need to do is get Zend to do the do the redirect after the HTTP request as been sent. Sorry if ive got the wrong end of the stick!